# How do I use FS to make a folder automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory, fs

I'm trying to use code to read an array and create folders using the name as one of the parameters if that name doesn't exist. I've been using fs to make a simple loop, like so

```
var streamsRepository = streamsRepositoryFactory(__dirname + '/streams.json');
var obj = streamsRepository.streams[i];
var i;

for(i = 0; i < streamsRepository.streams.length; i++) {
    var obj = streamsRepository.streams[i];

console.log('Folder '+obj.key+' is Created');


    if (!fs.existsSync('../audio/'+obj.key)){
        fs.mkdirSync('../audio/'+obj.key);

    }
}
```

But every time I keep getting the message.

```
Folder AAAA is Created
fs.js:796
  return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
                 ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '../audio/AAAA'
```

Comment: Shouldn't obj and i be declared as a global variable at the top rather than in the for loop.

Comment: How did you check for errors? Did you set up a try/catch? Try doing `try { fs.mkdirSync(path); } catch(e) { if ( e.code != 'EEXIST' ) throw e; }`

Comment: Okay, tried that. Its now telling me 

fs.js:796
  return binding.mkdir(pathModule._makeLong(path),
                 ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '../audio/

Comment: Seems like there is no `/audio` directory in which `mkdir` could create anything.

Comment: You can use 'fs-extra' module instead, it has APIs to well meet your needs.

Answer (score 10):

**Have a test below**

```
'use strict';
var fs = require('fs');
// fs.mkdirSync('folda'); // success
fs.mkdirSync('/parent-not-exists/folda'); 
// Failed,if parent folder isn't exists,will throw 
// Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/parent-not-exists/folda'
```

**solution**
use [mkdirp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mkdirp),Recursively mkdir, like `mkdir -p`

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');

mkdirp('/tmp/foo/bar/baz', function (err) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    else console.log('pow!')
});
```

Answer (score 2):

NVM, found a solution. all I had to do was specify the location better.

```
if (!fs.existsSync('/home/user/recorder/audio/'+obj.key)){
    fs.mkdirSync('/home/user/recorder/audio/'+obj.key);
    console.log ('Folder '+obj.key+' has been created');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just one line solution**

```
!fs.existsSync(`./assets/`) && fs.mkdirSync(`./assets/`, { recursive: true })
```